# How to get all names of a classes' classmethods in Python

Tags: python, reflection

I want to find out all classmethods of class `Something` below by using code reflection.
With all classmethods i mean all methods which are decorated with `@classmethod`. 
I don't actually know if that is the same.

```
class Something:
    @classmethod
    def a(cls):
        print('a')

    @staticmethod
    def b(cls):
        print('b')

    def c(self):
        print('c')
```

So in this case I expect getting a list which contains only `'a'`:

```
get_classmethod_names(Something) == ['a']
```

Comment: I will use the looked up names to feed an argparser and then use the found out names to call the function. You still may ask why and maybe rightfully so, because it looks like a stupid design decision. However, the code which i'm using reflection on is like it is and not subject to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be as simple as iterating through the classes attributes and checking for `classmethod` objects:

```
In [1]: class Something:
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def a(cls):
   ...:         print('a')
   ...:
   ...:     @staticmethod
   ...:     def b(cls):
   ...:         print('b')
   ...:
   ...:     def c(self):
   ...:         print('c')
   ...:

In [2]: [attr for attr, obj in vars(Something).items() if isinstance(obj, classmethod)]
Out[2]: ['a']
```

Note, if you care about *inherited* classmethods, then you have to check it for every class in your classe's method-resolution order, so:

```
In [3]: class BaseSomething:
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def u(cls):
   ...:         print('u')
   ...:
   ...: class Something(BaseSomething):
   ...:     @classmethod
   ...:     def a(cls):
   ...:         print('a')
   ...:
   ...:     @staticmethod
   ...:     def b(cls):
   ...:         print('b')
   ...:
   ...:     def c(self):
   ...:         print('c')
   ...:

In [4]: Something.mro()
Out[4]: [__main__.Something, __main__.BaseSomething, object]

In [5]: [
   ...:     attr
   ...:     for cls in Something.mro()
   ...:     for attr, obj in vars(cls).items()
   ...:     if isinstance(obj, classmethod)
   ...: ]
Out[5]: ['a', 'u']
```